# LTspice 1000A simulation

Tags: ltspice, high-current, voltage

I want to simulate a 1000A current flowing through a circuit in LTspice. The supply voltage is 230V AC @ 50Hz. This circuit will also have 0.05 milliohm in series with the load (this resistor acts as a shunt resistor.) The voltage drop across the resistor should be 50mV.

How do I go about simulating this in LTspice?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo4q7X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What do you want to learn from your simulation? You could make your load either a 1000 A AC current sink, or a 0.23 ohm resistor.

Comment: @ThePhoton, to be honest, I just want to learn how to simulate it and get the 50mV drop from the shunt resistor. I thought it would be easy by when I started to simulate it on LTSpice I got very confussed. In addition, when I calculated the 50mV, I did it by saying 1000A X 0.05mOhm. However, Since this is AC is the 50mV the amplitude of the sine wave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to do:

[image]

A couple notes here.  First, you have to define your source in "peak" value and not RMS.  For a sine wave, you just multiply the desired RMS value by 1.414 to get the peak value.

Second, the load here is just a basic current source that is the same frequency and is in phase with the voltage source.  You also have to do the same thing with the RMS value as you do with the voltage source.

Third, your measured values are so small compared to your excitation values that you might want to force a smaller maxiumum timestep in the `.tran` command like I've done here:

[image]

Lastly, one way to get the RMS values back is to plot the waveform for an **exact** number of cycles and <kbd>CTRL+leftclick</kbd> the colored name of the trace.  That's how I got those little boxes with Average and RMS values to pop up.  You can't get two boxes up at the same time.  I used some MSPaint magic for that.

Comment: How to you get the differential scope across the shunt (V in, out)? I can only do single ended probing.

Comment: @JoeyB  Right-click the plot window and choose "Add Traces".  Then for the expression type `V(in,out)` or `V(in)-V(out)`.  Alternatively, on the schematic left-click hold while on first node and release click on second node.